# React router with multiple hierarchical parameters

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I have a documentation component and I would like my urls to look like this:

```
url: myapp.com/docs
url: myapp.com/docs/document-1
url: myapp.com/docs/category-1/document-2
url: myapp.com/docs/category-1/category-2/document-2
```

I'm struggling setting up the routes.

I've tried a few things, including:

```
 <Route path="docs">
     <IndexRoute component={Docs} />
     <Route path=":path" component={Docs} />
 </Route>
```

This works well for `myapp.com/docs/document-1` but it does not work well with `myapp.com/docs/category-1/document-2`, meaning that `this.props.params.path` will return `document-1` in the first case but gets confused in the second.

I would like to get the path after `myapp.com/docs`. For example, for `myapp.com/docs/category-1/category-2/document-2` I would like to be able to pickup `/category-1/category-2/document-2`.

Any thoughts on how to accomplish that? Please let me know if the question is not clear enough.

note: I don't have control about the number of layers on the url.

Comment: Have you checked out the [React Router documentation on route matching](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/v3/docs/guides/RouteMatching.md)? You'll either need to nest routes or use multiple string patterns like you have above.

Answer (score 0):

This is what worked for me.

```
<Route path="**/*" component={Docs} />
```

And to capture it:

```
this.props.params.splat
```

If you want the whole path do:

```
this.props.params.splat.join('/')
```